# как открыть sublime text 3 с юнити для написания кода

Tags: c#, unity3d, sublime-text-3

подскажите как открыть sublime text 3 с unity для написания кода

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать sublime, он не выведет вам никаких подсказок. VS или Reader.

Answer (score 1):

`Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> Browse...`, затем выберете нужный .exe (расположенный в папке с *sublime text 3*).
[image]